# Spring CrudRepository findBy exclusionary?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a CrudRepository 'custom' find method that's working as follows:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, Integer>{

    List<Product> findAllByVendorID(int id);

}
```

And to call it I do the following:

```
List<Product> products = productRepository.findAllByVendorID(vendor.getId());
```

But if I want the opposite result, or all the products that aren't associated with that vendor id, is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should suffice.

```
   List<Product> findAllByVendorIDNot(int id);
```

You can extend this for multiple Id's as well

```
  List<Product> findAllByVendorIDNotIn(List<Integer> ids);
```